# Remove blue frame in Android Studio projects

Tags: android-studio, format

I'm new on Android Studio. I can't seem to figure out how to get rid of the header on my coding projects. Right under the utility bar that shows battery life and time and the reception icon, it displays the project name I created for the project. I tried choosing a blank activity when I started a new project but it is still there.

Can anyone help me with this, thanks a lot!

Johnny

Comment: I am not shure what you are trying to solve. Your title refers to a "blue frame", but the body of your question seems to be about the diplay of the project name. You might edit your question to be clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

The name of what you are trying to remove is the 'Action Bar'.

Go to your styles.xml file (project -> res -> values -> styles.xml

and change your app theme from this template:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    // some styles
</style>
```

to

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    // some styles
</style>
```

The keyword here is **No**ActionBar.

Comment: Thanks SupahSet! Worked like a charm!